# Using `htmlspecialchars()` to stop XSS attacks

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

How does using `htmlspecialchars()` **stop** XSS attacks?

Based on everything I researched, using this function allows you to *render* user input. According to my understanding, this means that if a user entered some html code into a form (or other input source), then you'll actually execute that code instead of simply displaying it. Again, how does this *stop* an attack?

If you look at the difference between using the function and not using it, clicking View Source gives you the following (on a call to `exec("dir") on a windows machine):
[Using htmlspecialchars()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgZdH.png)
[Not using it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VajKe.png)

As you can see, the difference is that `<DIR>` turned into `&lt;DIR&gt;` after using the function. So all it's doing is escaping all HTML characters? So it doesn't actually render anything? Would love a comprehensive answer to this.

Comment: Where did you get that? **PHP doesn't execute HTML.** Neither htmlspecialchars "renders" anything.

Comment: While most answers in the linked dupe only say that you should escape input, not many explain why. [Matt E's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45512141/240443) does a pretty good job, though: by escaping HTML characters, it prevents rendering `<script>` tags that a user might have maliciously submitted.

Comment: Also, only very unsuspecting users escape "input" or, worse yet, "user input". To protect from XSS you must escape ANY data going to be used in HTML context. So it's a very specific **output**, not input and **any data**, not only the "user supplied" one.

Comment: Yes, "all it's doing is escaping all HTML characters", so they don't interpreted as commands by the browser. That's all. HTML is interpreted (or rendered) by the browser, not PHP.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: `how does this stop an attack`....by neutralising the content, so it no longer contains anything a browser could execute, if/when that content comes to be sent to a browser.